# Updating a CloudFormation stack with a Cognito pool claims that we're adding attributes when we're not

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

Starting on Nov 7, 2018 we started getting the following error when updating our CloudFormation stacks:

```
Updating user pool schema is not allowed from cloudformation. Use the
AddCustomAttributes API or the AWS Cognito Console to update user pool
schema.
```

Our CF stacks don't have any changes to the custom attributes of the Cognito pool.  They only have changes to the `PostConfirmation` and `CustomMessage` triggers, as well the addition of API Gateway responses.

Does anybody know why we might be seeing this?  How can we avoid this error message?

Comment: Not an answer. But I'd advice you to stay cautious while using CloudFormation with Amazon Cognito. 
There is a known delete-recreate bug, as discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/9tienu/cognito_how_are_people_backing_up_and_replicating/)

Comment: We've been using it for a good 18 months and haven't ever had our pools deleted.  We do make sure every change goes through a staging environment, so we'd know if it was deleted, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly by luck, I've found an answer that allows me to get around this in an automated manner.

### How our scripts used to work

First, let me explain how this used to work.  I used to have the following set of cloudFormation scripts:

```
cognitoSetup.template  --> <Serverless Framework> --> <cognitoSetup.template updated with triggers>
```

So we'd setup the Cognito pool, run the Serverless Framework to add the Cognito Lambda functions, and then update the cognitoSetup.template file with the ARNs for the lambdas exported when the Serverless Framework ran.

### The Fix

Now, we include the ARNs for the Lambdas in the `cognitoSetup.template`. So now `cognitoSetup.template` looks like this:

```
   "CognitoUserPool": {
     "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
     ...
     "Properties": {
     ...
     "LambdaConfig": {
        "CustomMessage": "arn:aws:lambda:<our aws region>:<our account#>:function:main-<our stage>-onCognitoCustomMessage"
      }
    }
```

Note, we're setting this trigger ***before*** the lambda even exists.  The trigger just needs an ARN, and it doesn't seem to care that it's not there yet.  Then we run `sls deploy` which creates the actual Lambda function and everything works fine.

Now our scripts look like this:

```
cognitoSetup.template  --> <Serverless Framework>
```

Why does this fix this error?  I don't actually know.  CloudFormation seems to be fine with this modification but not okay with modifying the same file later in our process. But it works.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with deployment. For now we are deploying it without CustomMessage trigger and setting CustomMessage trigger manually after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

we removed the CustomMessage changes from our template and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Do you have a CICD system?  Did you write a program to re-add it or something?